# Give zabbix agent read permissions on root log files

Tags: centos, log-files, zabbix, user-permissions

I'm running zabbix-agent on a centos 7 machine under user/group zabbix. I want to give the zabbix user access to a couple of log files in folders under:

```
/var/log
/usr/local/cpanel/logs/
```

What is the best way to give that user access to those files. Since for example `/var/log/messages` is owned by root, I can't just chmod the files to zabbix. Also running the zabbix agent under root sounds like a bad plan.

What is the best approach? should I use setfacl?
If I use setfacl, should I add rights to all preceding folders as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could add **zabbix** user to **adm** group to read logs in `/var/log` and add to respective group to have access to `/usr/local/cpanel/logs/`.

> adm: Group adm is used for system monitoring tasks. Members of this
>   group can read many log files in /var/log, and can use xconsole.
>   Historically, /var/log was /usr/adm (and later /var/adm), thus the
>   name of the group.